# Please help me to clean up dead PHP documentation links (uk2.php.net)

Tags: support, status-completed, edits, clean-up

[There are 367 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*uk2.php*%22&submit=search) for `url:"*uk2.php*"`. It's currently dead. The only necessary thing is, to delete `uk2` subdomain, which works pretty fine. Please help me to clean  them.

Comment: It may even be permanently dead; it's no longer on [the list of mirrors](http://www.php.net/mirrors.php).

Comment: While you're at it, don't forget not to only change the link, but see if the post needs some editin' love too.

Comment: Not you... *me*. That's a tag I created (well, Anna told me about it).

Comment: I think best it to omit the `uk2` or `us2` and leave only `php.net[original URL]` isn't it? From what I saw, I'm being redirected to the proper sub domain.

Comment: @Asylum: Uff, in that case, sorry, I didn't get the edit reason :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Currently uk2 is down for a long time and no redirections are being added

Comment: genesis that's not my point.. I mean it's better not to "hard code" the sub domain as we can't rely on it to exist. `us2` might be down too tomorrow for all I know.

Comment: No problem, I should/could have been a little bit clearer, too. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Okay, I have edited the question before, to delete the subdomain completely,  and I'll do so

Comment: I'm working on this now...

Comment: @TheUnhandledException: thanks for the fix on my answer. The problem clearly stems from the sub-domains appearing in search results for doc pages — others, like myself, would have just copied/pasted the URLs.  Good to see the community fixing these dead links. +1 to the OP.

Comment: No problem @Andy! I upvoted a few of your answers, too. This meta question may be good to you :)

Comment: 399 links to [uk3.php.net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2auk3.php%2a%22&submit=search), 1,598 links to [us3.php.net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2aus3.php%2a%22&submit=search) and 2,025 links to [us2.php.net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2aus2.php%2a%22&submit=search) if anyone is crazy and bored enough.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ And also 305 [ca3.php.net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*ca3.php*%22&submit=search), 256 [ca2.php.net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*ca2.php*%22&submit=search) I believe they have server in a lot of country

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I might be crazy enough but sadly have to work today :-p Those aren't broken however, right? (At least not yet)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException: yeah, not yet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, fueled up with some food

[image: I didn't actually eat this]

I am ready to continue on with this quest!

<strike>FYI I have 50 questions per page in my search result and I am working off page two.</strike> I seem to be colliding with [nulluserexception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149052/nulluserexception) quite a bit all of a sudden.

Back at it now. It looks like between [NullUserException](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149052/nulluserexception), [HoLyVieR](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147981/holyvier), [Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158667/mat), and myself, all of these have been corrected! **Thanks guys!

Time for lunch now. I think I'll make a sandwich.

[image: Yummy]

Comment: I think my arteries clogged just looking at that. Looks delicious. ;)

Comment: @AnnaLear haha, same here :-) note the tooltip, what I actually ate for breakfast was far less interesting or meme-filled. However I have eaten a fried chicken waffle sandwich before and can arrest to the deliciousness!

Comment: I fixed 119 of them links; I also sprinkled in some minor edits to the same posts. Did I just win?

Comment: @AnnaLear All the poutine must've been more than enough training for your heart ;)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ You are #1 in the edits this week. I think so.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: looks like it's complete. I could use some of that waffle horror right now. With some maple syrup. And ice cream. And a cherry on top, maybe, for the style of it.

Comment: @HoLyVieR I was expecting that to totally flood the main page because of the bumps, but I am not seeing that. Hmmmm...