# Worst offending serial downvoters

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Earlier today, I got my first serial down vote (yay, milestones!), and it got me thinking.  SO users often participate primarily in a few primary tags, rarely straying into others.  Is it possible to identify the statistically "most naughty" communities when it comes to serial down voting (or, now that I think of it, other negative behavior)?  Granted, sometimes no one but the offender knows why they did something, but often it should be discoverable.

Examples (with Alice playing the part of the down-votee, and Mallory playing the part of the serial down voter):

- Alice closed a question of Mallory's in a certain tag.
- It was a revenge serial down vote, after an explained downvote left by Alice.
- Alice and Mallory are both primarily active in the same tag.

Has this been done, or can this be done?

If it explains my reasoning at all, I'm primarily active in [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and have yet to see this behavior.  This morning I tried to help out with [Please help me to clean up dead PHP documentation links (uk2.php.net)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112002/please-help-me-to-clean-up-dead-php-documentation-links-uk2-php-net), and received my serial down vote while doing so.  Is [php](/questions/tagged/php) frequented by bad sports, or is it impossible to tell if these things are connected?

Comment: I don't get why you think correcting links in [php] tags would be related to the downvotes you got.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the thing.  I don't think they should be, but they happened at the same time (and I haven't otherwise been too active recently), so now they're linked in my mind.  Ultimately, the reason I asked the question was because I don't want to go around thinking that php users are jerks when they are provably not.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/86/most-and-least-dangerous-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions

Comment: If we would get an answer (which involves some work from the development team, I suppose) then of course that might feel like accusing a group of users. Still, I feel it's interesting to know if statistics could give some clue. Maybe such statistics could even change the mechanism for detecting serial downvoting. So I think it's a useful question; voting to reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Serial downvotes are wiped away automatically, so it would be impossible to track.  Diamond moderators can't even see very much information on this.  We *might* be able to get a very rough idea by sifting through all the past suspension reasons, but that would be a lot of work for very little payoff.  There's not much inherent value in knowing that one *tag* gets more serial downvoters than another, since we treat each case on an individual user basis (that is, wipe away the votes, warn the downvoter, suspend if necessary).